# Is there any tools to check the memory and variable of running programme?

Tags: memory

I can use Wireshark to check the computer network and packages, and I got GDB debugger to check debug of the programme that I own the source, is there any tools for me to check the programme that I don't own the source, but I would like to check the memory usage of the programme for that? Can I ever check the assign of variable or similar information. Thanks.